# GitPython: Creating a lightweight tag

Tags: python-3.x, git, gitpython

I'm using `GitPython==3.0.3` to create some git tags. But since I'm tagging the preview version of our software, I wanted to create a lightweight tag instead of an annotated one, but for now I wasn't able to figure it out.

```py
def tagpackage(context: Context) -> None:
    logger.debug('Tag [{}] repo [{}] branch [{}]'
                 .format(context.version.getpreviewversion(), context.args.git_repo, context.args.git_branch))
    logger.info('Creating the tag')
    preview_tag = context.repo.create_tag(context.version.getpreviewversion(), ref=None)
    logger.info('Pushing tag')
    context.repo.remote('origin').push(preview_tag)
```

Quick explanation :

- `context.version.getpreviewversion()` is a string like this : 1.7.0-preview.1
- `context.repo` refers to the current [Repo object](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#module-git.repo.base)

It does generate the tag, and when I look on the github instance it does appear, but it appears like an annotated tag and not a lightweight.

I did found some examples but they never mention if it's going to create a lightweight or an annotated one, my experience is that they all produce an annotated one.

Thanks for all the consideration you'll be giving to this question.